# Excel VSTO - cm/inches to point conversion not accurate

Tags: excel, vsto, powerpoint, points

Been working on a custom ribbon tab with some functionality that resizes charts to certain size options that fit into template PowerPoint slide we have.

The conventional wisdom is use a standard cm to points conversion function at 28.35pts to 1cm. However, this doesn't seem to come out accurate.

E.g. if the input into the conversion function is 6.7cm, the chart embedded in PowerPoint ends up 6.88cm wide.

This has been tried:

- At various sizes
- Converting CM to inches and then inches to points
- Using the built-in method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-centimeterstopoints-method-excel

...and it never comes up accurate.

I have not been able to find any mention of "external factors" that may impact how it appears (such as display resolution, slide size, etc).

Any ideas why this would happen and what workaround options there are?

Answer (score 0):

Dividing the centimetres by 0.035278 allows you to more accurately convert from centimeters to points in excel VBA. They use 28.35 points to a centimeter - which is too rounded and produces errors. You could work it out for inches as well, by recording one macro to resize and then dividing the points number provided by your inches, to get a more accurate conversion figure.

Comment: Bonny I've done that and it still comes up wrong - cm2pts(16) comes back 16.18 and cm2pts(6) comes back 6.18 (in the one bit of code, using it to resize a chart to 16x6.
Not sure why the differential is 0.18 in both cases (which it is in the original question above too) as that's obviously not a consistent proportion. Any ideas? I've tried on different monitor sizes too and same issue.